# My website doesnt scale properly on Iphones

Tags: android, html, css, iphone

I'm designing a responsive website and it works well on most devices. I use two different resolution monitors, a lenovo tablet, and two android phones (galaxy S4 and sony Xperia). On all these it looks great

[Galaxy Screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66131799/screenshots/VoipAndroid.png)

[Sony Screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66131799/screenshots/voipSony.png)

However, on Iphones, my layout breaks in two ways.

1. The menu doesnt scale properly so the last option 'contact' breaks to a new line. It doesnt do this on any other phone, so why does it do it on iPhones?

[iPhone screenshot of menu](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66131799/screenshots/voipIphone1.PNG)

1. It creates a blank line on the right side of the site. I cant explain it very well so here is a screenshot

[iPhone screenshot of blank bar](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66131799/screenshots/voipIphone2.PNG)

It does both these issues on [iPhone 4 simulator](http://iphone4simulator.com/) so I dont think its just the one phone Im testing on.

Here is a link to the [website](http://www.voipstreet.com/testSite/index.html)

Here is the view port im using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

What is causing this?

Edit - All media queries I am using

```
    /*Center Logo when on mobile*/
    @media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 989px){
        #logo{
            text-align:center;
        }
    }
            /*Add margin top on desktops*/
            @media all and (min-width: 990px){
                #navigationPages li{
                    margin-top:25px;
                }
            } 
            /*Remove margin top when on mobile*/
            @media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 989px){
                #navigationPages li{
                    margin-top:5px;
                }
            }  

            /*Change font size of navigation on mobile*/
            @media screen and (max-width: 468px) {
                #navigationPages li {
                      font-size: .85em;
                }
                #navigationPages li a {
                     padding: 0.75em 0.6em;
                }
            } 
    /*Float icons right on medium sized screens*/
    @media all and (min-width: 628px) and (max-width: 989px){
        #headerIcons img{
            display:block;
            float:right;
            margin-left:15px;

        }
    } 

    /*float left again for phones*/
    @media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 627px){
        #headerIcons img{
            display:block;
            float:left;
            margin-left:15px;

        }
    } 
                    /*Change font size of navigation on mobile*/
                @media screen and (max-width: 814px) {
                    #cityBackground p {
                    font-size: 25px;
                    text-justify:inter-word;
                    }
                }
            /*Change font size of navigation on mobile*/
                @media screen and (max-width: 623px) {
                    #cityBackground p {
                    font-size: 17px;
                    text-justify:inter-word;
                    }
                }
/*Reduce button sizes on mobile*/
@media all and (max-width: 989px){
    #buttonHolder img{
        width:30%;
        display:block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
} 

/*center icons on mobile*/
@media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 989px){
    #icon1 img{

        display:block;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        min-width:162px;
    }
} 

    /*Center titles on mobile*/
    @media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 989px){
        .whoWhatWhyTitles{
           text-align:center;
           margin-top:25px;
           font-size:32px;
           margin-right:35px;
        }
    } 

    /*Remove padding of text on mobile*/
        @media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 989px){
            #whoWeAre p{
                margin-top:5px;
                font-size:20px;

                padding-left:0;
                width:99%;
                text-align:center;

            }
        } 

    /*Remove padding of text on mobile*/
        @media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 989px){
            #whatWeDo p{
                margin-top:5px;
                font-size:20px;
                padding-left:0;
                width:99%;
                text-align:center;

            }
        } 

    /*Remove padding of text on mobile*/
        @media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 989px){
            #whyChooseUs p{
                margin-top:5px;
                font-size:20px;

                padding-left:0;
                width:99%;
                text-align:center;

            }
        } 

    /*Remove padding of text on mobile*/
        @media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 623px){
            #footerThin p{
                margin-left:0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the media queries you are using?

Comment: A link would be useful too.

Comment: The above post has a link to the website. I will edit post to include media queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What's Going On

The reason that the screen is going to wide is that the header isn't changing at all. This is why it's going off the screen on the iPhone shot. The good news is that we don't need a media query for it at all. We can just set it to have a `max-width` of `100%` of the screen. Add the code below to your stylesheet and let me know if that fixes it.

### Code

CSS:

```
#logo img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

CSS Alternative 1: (This will give a little bit of padding on each side).

```
#logo img {
    max-width:96%;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:auto;
}
```

### Screenshots

Current:

[image]

With New CSS:

[image]

With Alternative CSS:

[image]

Also, you need to add `height:auto` to the Learn More and Get Started buttons, to prevent them from being stretched.

## Edit To Comments

You asked about the menu going to two lines. If you change your padding, it should fix that.

Current CSS:

```
#navigationPages li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.75em 1.5em;
}
```

Working CSS:

```
#navigationPages li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.75em 1em;
}
```

Comment: This was a very helpful post! Wish I could upvote twice. The only other issue im having is the menu wrapping to a new line. It doesnt do it on my android phones. Is this just because my android phones have larger screens?

Comment: Glad to help! Yes, the issue is that all mobile devices have different screen widths. I've found though that if I can scale it on a computer screen, I'll be good as long as I have my viewport `meta` tags correct. To the menu specifically, one thing I normally do is change the menu to a dropdown. I designed IndyGreekFest.org to do that, open it up and resize down. The menu is replaced with a dropdown `select`. You could do something like that.

Comment: Another option would be changing the `font-size` or `padding` or `margin` of the menu. I'll take a look and see if I can tweak it to fit. **Edit:** I've added a padding tweak that should take care of it.

Comment: This was another great solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your header image is too wide. The image itself isn't scaling properly (or at all). Looking at the properties for the image, here are the dimensions I see:

410px × 75px (scaled to 348px × 64px)

The iPhone screen is 320px wide, so you have 28 extra pixels hanging out over there on the side causing the extra "white space", which is causing you to have a horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile phones are tricky to work with!

I just took a look at ur css. your logo had a `width: 348px`, set it to `width:100%` after it resizes past `349px` that should fix it.